# how to move everything in a directory except the sub-directories to another directory?

Tags: command-line, mv

I was cleaning my home (`/home`) when i felt the need for this.Help me move the files (with no extension) to another directory.However i want to keep the directories in the home intact. Various services depend on them

Comment: There are also files in there (without extension) you don't want to move!

Comment: find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/TargetDirectory

Comment: @NonStandardModel please write it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to move just the files and not the directories nor the files in the directories. You can use the `find` command with `~` (=home) as argument and also use the `maxdepth 1` (search only the parent directory) and `type f` (file). The result (all files in given directory) is than piped to `xargs` (the -0 option is to ignore special meanings of some chars) that executes the **move**. `mv -t TargetDirectory` moves the input that was produced by `find` command into TargetDirectory.

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t Path/To/Target/Directory
```

References: [mv](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?mv)  [find](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?find)  [xargs](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?xargs)

Answer (score 0):

Moving the files with extensions to `/target/directory`, assuming regular notion of extensions:

```
find ~ -type f -name '?*.?*' -exec mv -t /target/directory/ {} +
```

This will find and move files recursively starting from your home directory.

I have used `?*.?*` instead of just `*.*` so that hidden files in the form `.foobar` and files like `foobar.` are excluded.

If you do not want to traverse the subdirectories (i.e. non-recursively):

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '?*.?*' -exec mv -t /target/directory/ {} +
```

If you want to move all files regardless of having an extension:

```
find ~ -type f -exec mv -t /target/directory/ {} +
```

Non recursively:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t /target/directory/ {} +
```